# how to add a scrollbar to jquery mobile select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```html
 <select id="strategies" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" class="selectpicker">
                            <option>Service Strategies</option>
                            <option value="50-Peer and/or Family Delivered">50-Peer and/or Family Delivered</option>
                            <option value="51-Psychcoeducation">51-Psychcoeducation</option>
                            <option value="52-Family Support">52-Family Support</option>
                            <option value="53-Supportive Education">53-Supportive Education</option>
                            <option value="54-Part W/Law Enforcement">54-Part W/Law Enforcement</option>
                            <option value="55-Peer and/or Family Delivered">55-Peer and/or Family Delivered</option>
                            <option value="56-Psychcoeducation">56-Psychcoeducation</option>
                            <option value="57-Family Support">57-Family Support</option>
                            <option value="58-Supportive Education">58-Supportive Education</option>
                            <option value="59-Part W/Law Enforcement">59-Part W/Law Enforcement</option>
                            <option value="60-Peer and/or Family Delivered">60-Peer and/or Family Delivered</option>
                        </select>
```

I have a a select menu in my j query mobile site and i need to add scroll bar to select menu when it shows more number of options.how to do this..than x in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically , if you are using native select , then you wouldn't need to worry about it, the system will take care of that...
if you want to add custom scrollbar, then you need a very good reason for it...
(you will loose a lot of the stability of native compnents when using custom thins)
if after all of that you still think you gotta have a custom select, i would suggest using bootstrap/semantic ui solutions for these casaes
you should check out :
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ (for bootstrap)
and:
http://semantic-ui.com/

Comment: it' gud..but i need a scroll option when my select menu is long

Comment: if you are using native select, then the scroll is allowed automatic, you can easily try this on your phone here is a fiddle for you to test on your mobile :

http://jsfiddle.net/pqsmr6p5/

Comment: the thing with native , is that you can't really change its styling.... (you can to a certain point, but its not recommended) so no, you leave the jqm styles aside, but only for select... if i understand correctly